# Agrupar consulta por registros similares mas não identicos

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, query

Preciso migrar uma base de dados (de `SQL Server` para `PostgreSQL` e estou criando um `ETL` interativo em `PHP` para realizar essa mudança), que tem uns 10 anos, uns 2 milhões de registros na tabela de `clientes` que **não** tem verificação ou lógica de cadastro único, no caso `CPF` ou `CNPJ`.

E o grande problema disso é que eu tenho os seguintes cadastros na tabela de `cliente`: `[` `banco bradesco s.a.`,`banco bradesco`,`banco bradesco sa`,`bradesco sa`
,`banco do bradesco`,`bradesco seguros`,`bradesco curitiba`,`bradesco` `]` e um outro caso: `[` `walmart`,`supermercado walmart` `]`, e nenhum desses tem `CPF` ou `CNPJ`, sendo esses um exemplo de milhares possíveis. Meu objetivo é identificar eles e mostrar para o usuário que ele pode transformar todos em um só no novo banco de dados (mas isso é outra coisa).

No exemplo acima é a tabela `cliente`, e o valor(nome) é o que está na coluna `razao_social`, sendo **essa coluna o ponto de partida** para iniciar a verificação.

Já pesquisei, já estudei um esquema onde eu crio uma tabela, coloco os nomes lá e procuro os nomes nessa tabela usando um `LIKE %`, mas isso é muito custoso. Porem, uma alternativa.

Minha questão aqui é, consigo trazer todos os resultados parecidos, mas não idênticos, sem estabelecer um parâmetro em uma `query` ?

Agradeço.

*Obs.¹ Já avaliei o risco desse negócio com a questão com nomes comuns, tal como `panificadora`, `mercado`, `supermercado`, `posto` e ainda sim, preciso persistir nessa solução que citei no tópico.*

*Obs.² Adiantei um [SQLFIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9b532/1) para quem puder testar a query.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meu ver, a primeira coisa que você deve obter é a lista de termos usados em determinada coluna ([cuja resposta tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/106282/1314276)):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
    @RowData nvarchar(2000),
    @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN 
    Declare @Cnt int
    Set @Cnt = 1

    While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
    Begin
        Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
        Select 
            Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))

        Set @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
        Set @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
    End

    Insert Into @RtnValue (data)
    Select Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))

    Return
END

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitAll(@SplitOn nvarchar(5))
RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
    Id int identity(1,1),
    Data nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE My_Cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Nome FROM dbo.clientes
DECLARE @description varchar(50)

OPEN My_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @description
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RtnValue
    SELECT Data FROM dbo.Split(@description, @SplitOn)
   FETCH NEXT FROM My_Cursor INTO @description
END
CLOSE My_Cursor
DEALLOCATE My_Cursor

RETURN

END

SELECT DISTINCT Data FROM dbo.SplitAll(N' ')
```

Com essa lista de palavras, você pode trazer partições da sua tabela a partir dos termos encontrados. Isto é um trabalho humano, infelizmente, mas com ele, as operações de `LIKE` ficam mais razoáveis.

Ainda, se não quiser usar o `LIKE`, minha sugestão é a implementação [da função da distância de Levenshtein em SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734606/1314276), a qual transcrevo abaixo, da resposta mencionada:

```
-- =============================================
-- Computes and returns the Levenshtein edit distance between two strings, i.e. the
-- number of insertion, deletion, and sustitution edits required to transform one
-- string to the other, or NULL if @max is exceeded. Comparisons use the case-
-- sensitivity configured in SQL Server (case-insensitive by default).
-- http://blog.softwx.net/2014/12/optimizing-levenshtein-algorithm-in-tsql.html
-- 
-- Based on Sten Hjelmqvist's "Fast, memory efficient" algorithm, described
-- at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13525/Fast-memory-efficient-Levenshtein-algorithm,
-- with some additional optimizations.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Levenshtein](
    @s nvarchar(4000)
  , @t nvarchar(4000)
  , @max int
)
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @distance int = 0 -- return variable
          , @v0 nvarchar(4000)-- running scratchpad for storing computed distances
          , @start int = 1      -- index (1 based) of first non-matching character between the two string
          , @i int, @j int      -- loop counters: i for s string and j for t string
          , @diag int          -- distance in cell diagonally above and left if we were using an m by n matrix
          , @left int          -- distance in cell to the left if we were using an m by n matrix
          , @sChar nchar      -- character at index i from s string
          , @thisJ int          -- temporary storage of @j to allow SELECT combining
          , @jOffset int      -- offset used to calculate starting value for j loop
          , @jEnd int          -- ending value for j loop (stopping point for processing a column)
          -- get input string lengths including any trailing spaces (which SQL Server would otherwise ignore)
          , @sLen int = datalength(@s) / datalength(left(left(@s, 1) + '.', 1))    -- length of smaller string
          , @tLen int = datalength(@t) / datalength(left(left(@t, 1) + '.', 1))    -- length of larger string
          , @lenDiff int      -- difference in length between the two strings
    -- if strings of different lengths, ensure shorter string is in s. This can result in a little
    -- faster speed by spending more time spinning just the inner loop during the main processing.
    IF (@sLen > @tLen) BEGIN
        SELECT @v0 = @s, @i = @sLen -- temporarily use v0 for swap
        SELECT @s = @t, @sLen = @tLen
        SELECT @t = @v0, @tLen = @i
    END
    SELECT @max = ISNULL(@max, @tLen)
         , @lenDiff = @tLen - @sLen
    IF @lenDiff > @max RETURN NULL

    -- suffix common to both strings can be ignored
    WHILE(@sLen > 0 AND SUBSTRING(@s, @sLen, 1) = SUBSTRING(@t, @tLen, 1))
        SELECT @sLen = @sLen - 1, @tLen = @tLen - 1

    IF (@sLen = 0) RETURN @tLen

    -- prefix common to both strings can be ignored
    WHILE (@start < @sLen AND SUBSTRING(@s, @start, 1) = SUBSTRING(@t, @start, 1)) 
        SELECT @start = @start + 1
    IF (@start > 1) BEGIN
        SELECT @sLen = @sLen - (@start - 1)
             , @tLen = @tLen - (@start - 1)

        -- if all of shorter string matches prefix and/or suffix of longer string, then
        -- edit distance is just the delete of additional characters present in longer string
        IF (@sLen <= 0) RETURN @tLen

        SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, @start, @sLen)
             , @t = SUBSTRING(@t, @start, @tLen)
    END

    -- initialize v0 array of distances
    SELECT @v0 = '', @j = 1
    WHILE (@j <= @tLen) BEGIN
        SELECT @v0 = @v0 + NCHAR(CASE WHEN @j > @max THEN @max ELSE @j END)
        SELECT @j = @j + 1
    END

    SELECT @jOffset = @max - @lenDiff
         , @i = 1
    WHILE (@i <= @sLen) BEGIN
        SELECT @distance = @i
             , @diag = @i - 1
             , @sChar = SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1)
             -- no need to look beyond window of upper left diagonal (@i) + @max cells
             -- and the lower right diagonal (@i - @lenDiff) - @max cells
             , @j = CASE WHEN @i <= @jOffset THEN 1 ELSE @i - @jOffset END
             , @jEnd = CASE WHEN @i + @max >= @tLen THEN @tLen ELSE @i + @max END
        WHILE (@j <= @jEnd) BEGIN
            -- at this point, @distance holds the previous value (the cell above if we were using an m by n matrix)
            SELECT @left = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(@v0, @j, 1))
                 , @thisJ = @j
            SELECT @distance = 
                CASE WHEN (@sChar = SUBSTRING(@t, @j, 1)) THEN @diag                    --match, no change
                     ELSE 1 + CASE WHEN @diag < @left AND @diag < @distance THEN @diag    --substitution
                                   WHEN @left < @distance THEN @left                    -- insertion
                                   ELSE @distance                                        -- deletion
                                END    END
            SELECT @v0 = STUFF(@v0, @thisJ, 1, NCHAR(@distance))
                 , @diag = @left
                 , @j = case when (@distance > @max) AND (@thisJ = @i + @lenDiff) then @jEnd + 2 else @thisJ + 1 end
        END
        SELECT @i = CASE WHEN @j > @jEnd + 1 THEN @sLen + 1 ELSE @i + 1 END
    END
    RETURN CASE WHEN @distance <= @max THEN @distance ELSE NULL END
END
```

Uso:

```
... WHERE dbo.Levenshtein(@Coluna1, @Coluna2, 5) <= 5
```

Não precisa ser 5 o coeficiente máximo de diferença. Pelos testes, você vai saber qual o melhor coeficiente a aplicar.

Comment: Opá, isso chegou muito, mas muito próximo do que eu realmente queria, e esse próximo já é o suficiente para começar. Inclusive essa função abriu possibilidade para outras coisas. Muito obrigado pela resposta fera.